# Почему не работает загрузка в nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Использую multer.
Мой роутер:

```
upload.post('/', function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)

});
```

Моя форма:

```
<form id="photo-form" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/upload">
        <label>
            <input id="files-field" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
        </label>
            <hr>
            <input type="submit">
</form>
```

В app.js у меня есть:

```
var app = express();
var multer  = require('multer')
app.use(multer({ dest: './uploads'}))
```

В итоге `req.body` и `req.file` у меня `{}`, то есть нечего не приходит. В чем может быть проблема?

UPD Вопрос решен. Просто нужно было указать `name` в теге `input` таким же как и в `input` загрузки файла.

Answer (score 1):

Я получал post так, правда это не экспрес

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function (data) {
        body += data;
    });
    req.on('end', function () {
        console.log(body);
    });
}
```

Думаю основная идея работы с POST понятна, сначала по .on('data') получаем данные и склеиваем их, а потом по .on('end') делаем что-то с полученным результатом

Answer (score 1):

В общем проблема была в том, что я не поставил атрибут `name` в теге `input`.